# Missing referer header in Chrome when using code snippet

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I created an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53219867/310601) for HERE maps autocomplete API on Stack Overflow and I'm having an issue with the `HTTP_REFERER` header not being sent when using Chrome browser (works fine w/ Edge and IE).

This causes a problem since the ajax call to the API returns 401 (unauthorized) in the code snippet.  The API relies on the `HTTP_REFERER` header as a means to prevent misuse.

Looking at the problem I noticed that the generated `iframe` element doesn't have a `src` attribute and that it appears that this is a known [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226858) in Chromium.

Is there anyway to overcome this?  Maybe add a dummy `src` attribute set as https://stacksnippets.net/?

**EDIT**: The dummy `src` attribute didn't work, but setting `srcdoc` attribute did allow `HTTP_REFERER` header to be included in request.

[Documentation](http://devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe.html) states the following for `srcdoc` attribute.

> The content of the page that the embedded context is to contain. *This
>   attribute is expected to generally be used together with the sandbox
>   attribute*. If a browser supports the srcdoc attribute, it will
>   override the content specified in the src attribute (if present). If a
>   browser does NOT support the srcdoc attribute, it will show the file
>   specified in the src attribute instead (if present).

Comment: In the mean time, would it be possible to add yourself an iframe inside your snippet with the desired srcdoc?

Comment: According to the specification, the referer header is an optional header, so you cannot depend on it being always send

Comment: While StackSnippets could be improved in that regard, I would still consider this a bug in the HERE API.

Comment: @Bergi It's not a bug in the HERE API, restricting access by referer is an optional setting, similar to Google API [restrictions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152066/).  HERE maps has kindly added `stacksnippets.net` as an allowed domain so we have to work with what we've been provided or not access the API at all.